# How max-width is different from width if we assign value in percentage?

Tags: css

I was reading a bootstrap css file in which col-md-6 was assigned as

```
max-width:50%;
```

After doing it as width instead of `max-width` the result was same as before so, why do we need to use `max-width`.

Comment: Could you please elaborate, what do you mean by " already it is in percentage"? I mean what you are referring about, it is already set as a width?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it means that the element won't ever become wider than 50% of its parent element.

So especially in responsive web design, if you define an elements width as `width: 300px`and `max-width: 50%`, it will be 300px on wider screens where the (reponsive) parent can be wider than 600px, and if a smaller screen forces the parent element to become narrower, the child will always remain at 50% of the parent's width, which will then be less than 300px.

```css
.parent {
  width: 80%;
  background: yellow;
}

.child {
  width: 300px;
  max-width: 50%;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    content
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But don't you think     max-width: 300px;  width: 50%; in child do the same thing

Answer (score 0):

This is how max-width works.

If the content is larger than the maximum width, it will automatically change the width of the element.

If the content is smaller than the maximum width, the max-width property has no effect.

Note: This prevents the value of the width property from becoming larger than max-width. The value of the max-width property overrides the width property.

Source:
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_max-width.asp

Comment: The question (as I understand it) is not about how `max-width` works but what the point of setting a limiter value (`max-width`) which is relative rather than absolute.

Answer (score 0):

if we set a div to max-with of 50%, then it will limit the content to 50% of the container.

But if we the content is lesser then 50% of the container, then the width of the div will be actual content width.

By the way, max-width is supported by all major browsers including IE7+ so you shouldn't be afraid of using it.

Please go through the below link for details and examples.

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_max-width.asp